# javascript. How to pass the "this" object after ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this code:

```
$(function(){
    $("#CASA").click(function(){
        rsExecute("rs/rs_luci.php","premi",1,function(cc){});
        var col=$( this ).css( "background-color" );
        setColor(this, 'yellow');
        setTimeout(setColor,1000,this,col);
    });
});

function setColor(obj,clr){
    $(obj).css( "background-color", clr );
}
```

*rsExecute* makes a call via ajax. *function(cc){}* is executed on success.

I've tried to change the code like this:

```
$(function(){
    $("#CASA").click(function(){
        rsExecute("rs/rs_luci.php","premi",1,function(cc){
            var col=$( this ).css( "background-color" );
            setColor(this, 'yellow');
            setTimeout(setColor,1000,this,col);
        });
    });
});

function setColor(obj,clr){
    $(obj).css( "background-color", clr );
}
```

but it doesn't work because **this** is undefined.

Is there a way to pass **this** object to the function inside *rsExecute*?

Comment: Please read [How does the “this” keyword work?](/q/3127429/4642212).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Save it to a variable, traditionally named 'that', and pass that variable using the closure.

```
$(function(){
    $("#CASA").click(function(){
        var that = this;
        rsExecute("rs/rs_luci.php","premi",1,function(cc){
            var col=$( that ).css( "background-color" );
            setColor(that, 'yellow');
            setTimeout(setColor,1000,that,col);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: This was the best approach more than a decade ago. Much better alternatives exist today: `(cc) => {`…`}` or `function(cc){`…`}.bind(this)`. But all of this is already suggested in the fourth most frequently linked JS question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Agreed, this was using the same conventions that the OP had in original snippet.